# Cannot redefine property: $router, possible duplication of Vue.use(VueRouter)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a few routes in my Vue App. However, refreshing the page will cause never ending loop only in particular 2 routes. The error that I received from chrome console is

```
VM10283:55826 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $router
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Function.install (<anonymous>:55826:10)
    at Function.Vue.use (app.js:62595)
    at Module../node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js (<anonymous>:57490:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (<anonymous>:20:30)
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (<anonymous>:71691:68)
    at __webpack_require__ (<anonymous>:20:30)
    at Object.0 (<anonymous>:74685:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (<anonymous>:20:30)
    at <anonymous>:84:18
```

Below are my codes

**app.js**

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from '@/js/router'
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    hash: false,
    routes
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    router,
    components: { App },
    template: '<App/>',
});
```

**router/index.js**

```
import Home from '@/js/components/Home.vue';
import store from '@/js/store'

export default [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        beforeEnter: publicAuth,
        component: Home,
        meta: {
            title: 'Home',
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/user/profile',
        name: 'user.profile',
        beforeEnter: auth,
        component: Profile,
        meta: {
            title: 'Profile',
        }
    },
...
```

After searching on SO i realized that it is probably caused by `Vue.use(VueRouter)`, and i have tried all the methods on the web and no solution is to be found.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add that "@/js/router" file.

Comment: @hemasundarGinni i have updated my question with router/index.js